procedimientos almacenados. Web VisualStudio C# NetCore
Procedimientos almacenados. VisualStudio C# NetCore.
ERROR:An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: ESTADOS.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior).Checando. 

en SQL si funciona el procedimiento almacenado.
(LEFT JOIN Estados AS EDOS1 ON DetPks1.Origen = Edos1.IdEdos)
LEFT JOIN Estados AS RES1 ON DetPks1.Residente = RES1.IdEdos))

Y en el proyecto da ese error. EL MODELO esta asi.
public double? Origen { get; set; } 
public string ESTADOS { get; set; } 
public double? Residente { get; set; } 
public string EdosRes { get; set; })  

Cuando quito el campo EdosRes del modelo y de sql, todo funciona bien, muestra los datos en el proyecto. COMO LE HAGO O QUE ME FALTA, PARA QUE FUNCIONE, ES UN ARCHIVO DE CATALOGO QUE SE USA MAS DE UNA VEZ (SON ESTADOS DE LA REPUBLICA MEXICANA) QUE SE USA PARA SABER DONDE NACION Y DONDE RESIDE ACTUALMENTE.

El error habla de un diccionario, estas utilizando alguno?
